# unexpected token: INNER required: SET : line: 2

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I am trying to update a column in a table (tblStructures.State) when the values exit in another table (tblStructure_merged_new). But the update inner join did not work.

```
UPDATE `tblStructures` 
INNER JOIN tblStructures_merged_new ON `tblStructures`.`Hole` =tblStructures_merged_new.`Hole` 
SET `tblStructures`.`State`  = '0' 
WHERE `tblStructures`.`From_m`= tblStructures_merged_new.`From_m` 
AND `tblStructures`.`Struct1`  = tblStructures_merged_new.`Struct1`;
```

The error message is

> SQL Error [42581]: UCAExc:::5.0.1 unexpected token: INNER required:
> SET : line: 2

Any ideas of why is not working?

Comment: this looks very wrong you get an uaccess error message but posted code for mysql, so correct your code

Comment: okay, thanks, here is the code working in access but not in dbeaver:                 
 UPDATE tblStructures INNER JOIN tblStructures_merged_new ON (tblStructures.Struct1 = tblStructures_merged_new.Struct1) 
AND (tblStructures.From_m = tblStructures_merged_new.From_m) AND (tblStructures.Hole = tblStructures_merged_new.Hole)
SET tblStructures.State = "0";                    Again the error is SQL Error [42581]: UCAExc:::5.0.1 unexpected token: INNER required: SET.

Comment: your coede doesn't look wrong but you are only posting a part of the error

Answer (score 0):

Switch order of lines

```
UPDATE `tblStructures` 
SET `tblStructures`.`State`  = '0' 
FROM `tblStructures`
INNER JOIN tblStructures_merged_new ON `tblStructures`.`Hole` =tblStructures_merged_new.`Hole` 
WHERE `tblStructures`.`From_m`= tblStructures_merged_new.`From_m` 
AND `tblStructures`.`Struct1`  = tblStructures_merged_new.`Struct1`;
```

Comment: that wouldn't work in MS access